# Can Python combine Excel rows?

Tags: python, excel

I want to combine rows in an Excel worksheet based on the same value of title.

I am wondering that how can I do that by using Python 2.7?

The spreadsheet I have is :

[image]

The output file should look like this:

[image]

Thanks,
Jennifer.

Comment: Check out https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ . I'm not sure if it's supported in python 2, but you should strongly consider upgrading to python 3 anyway as python 2 is outdated and no longer supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind loading your Excel to a dataframe with pandas, this is a possible solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Title': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
                   'Version': [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'Board': ['S1', 'S2', 'S1', 'S2', 'S4', 'S1']},
                  columns=['Title', 'Version', 'Board'])

print(df) 

#  Title  Version Board
# 0     A        1    S1
# 1     A        1    S2
# 2     B        1    S1
# 3     B        2    S2
# 4     B        3    S4
# 5     C        4    S1


print(df.groupby(['Title']).agg(lambda x: ','.join(sorted(set(map(str, x))))).reset_index())

#   Title Version     Board
# 0     A       1     S1,S2
# 1     B   1,2,3  S1,S2,S4
# 2     C       4        S1
```

Otherwise you'd have to manually fiddle with the sheet with openpyxl.